# Where can I see the processes running at startup?

Tags: linux, process, startup, backtrack

I'm using backtrack5 R2 and sometimes when I log in the information showed says that `There is 1 zombie process`, where can I see what process is running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ps` command to watch currently running processes.

`ps aux` will give more verbose output. If the value in STATE column equal to Z, then you know it is a zombie process.

I don't think that zombie proccesses are included in bootstrap sequence on purpose. It's rather a shatter from another process. Maybe via `ps` command you will be able to figure out what it was exactly.

Comment: Thanks a lot, how can I know if the process should remain in there or if I kill it?

Comment: I never killed a zombie in my entire life. I don't think it should be a problem to have zombie processes. At least when their number is low.

Comment: What do you mean for "the number is low"?

Comment: I am not sure about exact number, but if I'd had, say, 10 zombies I would not be bothered. So if you have just one, it's probably ok.

Comment: Well, the thing is not about the number of zombies, it's about knowing what is going on, since backtrack is a distro for security, I think it's fair to know what's happening, don't you?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process

Comment: And by the way, even if a distro claims to be supersecure, it doesn't mean it is bug-free, does it?

Comment: Yes, I know distros are not bug-free, but it doesn't mean you have to ignore what's going on, backtrack is for security purposes, not super secure, thanks anyway!! ;)

Comment: @poz2k4444 A zombie process is a normal thing, it happens sometimes. It's unrelated to security. You can't kill a zombie, it's already dead.